# Getting syntax error for REGEXP in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I have switched from mysql 5.7 to 8 and I am getting syntax error on below query :-

```
SELECT * FROM rainy_day_handler_macro WHERE FLOW_NAME = "XX"  AND SERVICE_TYPE IN ('*' ,'*') 
            AND VNF_TYPE IN ( 'xx' , '*') AND ERROR_CODE IN ('MSOWorkFlowException'  ,'*') AND WORK_STEP IN ('*' , '*' ) 
        AND ( 'XX' REGEXP rainy_day_handler_macro.REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE OR REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE = '*') 
            AND SERVICE_ROLE IN ( "*" , '*') 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1 REGEXP REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE THEN 0 WHEN ERROR_CODE != '*' THEN 1 WHEN VNF_TYPE != '*' 
            THEN 2 WHEN SERVICE_TYPE != '*' THEN 3 WHEN SERVICE_ROLE != '*' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END LIMIT 1;
```

Error- SQL Error: 3688, SQLState: HY000

- Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 1.

Comment: And this has what exactly to do with java?

Comment: Examine the data contained in the column `REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE`. What is that string? Is it a valid regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to QUOTE the regular expressions from the stirngs

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    rainy_day_handler_macro
WHERE
    FLOW_NAME = 'XX'
        AND SERVICE_TYPE IN ('*' , '*')
        AND VNF_TYPE IN ('xx' , '*')
        AND ERROR_CODE IN ('MSOWorkFlowException' , '*')
        AND WORK_STEP IN ('*' , '*')
        AND ('XX' REGEXP QUOTE(rainy_day_handler_macro.REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE)
        OR REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE = '*')
        AND SERVICE_ROLE IN ('*' , '*')
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN 1 REGEXP QUOTE(REG_EX_ERROR_MESSAGE) THEN 0
    WHEN ERROR_CODE != '*' THEN 1
    WHEN VNF_TYPE != '*' THEN 2
    WHEN SERVICE_TYPE != '*' THEN 3
    WHEN SERVICE_ROLE != '*' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
END
LIMIT 1;
```